# How to update a panel outside a datable table in a tab from a commandbutton

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

please i have a commandbutton in a datatable that updates a panel. I get org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find component for expression when i click on the commandbutton.

```
<p:tab title="Register Vendor" id="tabtab">

    <p:panel id="ven">

        <h:panelGrid columns="6">
            <p:outputLabel value="Vendor Name: " for="vname"/>
            <p:inputText id="vname" required="true" value="#{bank.vendor_name}" />
            <p:message for="vname"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Vendor Bank: " for="bank"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="bank" value="#{bank.bankmode.bankName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Bank required">

                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select Bank--" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{bank.bankmodel}"
                               var="singlevalue"  
                               itemLabel="#{singlevalue.bankName}"
                               itemValue="#{singlevalue.bankName}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>


            <p:message for="bank"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Vendor Account Number: " for="anum"/>
            <p:inputText id="anum" required="true" value="#{bank.vendor_acct}" requiredMessage="Account Number required" />
            <p:message for="anum"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Vendor Contact Address: " for="adress"/>
            <p:inputTextarea id="adress" required="true" value="#{bank.vendor_address}" requiredMessage="Contact Address required" />
            <p:message for="adress"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Vendor Email Address: " for="email"/>
            <p:inputText id="email" required="true" label="email" size="40"
                         requiredMessage="Please enter your email address."
                         validatorMessage="Invalid email format"
                         value="#{bank.vendor_email}">

                <f:validateRegex
                    pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />

            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="email" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Vendor Phone Number " for="pnum"/>
            <p:inputText id="pnum" required="true" value="#{bank.vendor_phone}" requiredMessage="Phone number required" />
            <p:message for="pnum"/>

            <p:commandButton value="save" process="@this vname,bank,anum,adress,email,pnum" update="singleTB,:templateForm:growl,ven" actionListener="#{bank.insertData}" />

        </h:panelGrid>




        <p:outputPanel style="margin-left: 800px;">
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" style="width:150px; margin-right: 10px;" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
            <p:commandButton value="Search"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel id="singleTB">

        <p:dataTable var="ven_tab"
                     selectionMode="true"
                     rowKey="#{ven_tab.id}"
                     value="#{bank.vendorList}"                                         
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  
                     {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
                     {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "
                     paginator="true" style="margin-bottom:20px"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Id"/>
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorId}"/>

            </p:column>

            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorName}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorName}"  required="true"  requiredMessage="Name is required" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>


            </p:column>

            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Phone Number"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorPnum}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Email"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorEmail}"/>

            </p:column>
            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Contact Address"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorContact}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Bank"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorBank}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vendor Account Number"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{ven_tab.vendorAcct}"/>        
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:32px" exportable="false">
                <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-edit" style="margin-left: -5px;" process="@this" update=":tabtab:ven,:templateForm:growl" actionListener="#{bank.select(ven_tab)}" />

            </p:column>


        </p:dataTable> 
        <p:contextMenu for="singleTB" rendered="#{bank.status}" >
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" process="@this singleTB" update=":templateForm:growl,singleTB" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{bank.deleteCar}"/>
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:panel style="margin-top:-50px; float: right;">
            <h3>Export table Data Only</h3>

            <h:commandLink immediate="true">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/excel.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="singleTB " fileName="report" pageOnly="true"/>
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:commandLink immediate="true">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/pdf.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="singleTB" fileName="report" pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:commandLink immediate="true">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/csv.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="singleTB" fileName="report" pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>

            <h:commandLink immediate="true">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/xml.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="singleTB" fileName="report" pageOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:panel>

    </p:panel>


</p:tab>
```

I have a masterpage that contains the form. Pls how do i resolve this issue. I have been on it for sometime now

Comment: At least you should mention which commandbutton and which table you are talking about because the code you added have more than one command button/table. Also add full error message.

Comment: there is only one commandbutton in the datatable like i specified and one datatable in the code i sent

Comment: Have you tried with `ven` only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if the creator vote me down. The solution is :

```
<p:tabView id="tabview">
            <p:tab title="Register Vendor" id="tabtab">

                <h:form id="tabForm">
                    <p:panel id="ven">
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel id="singleTB">
```

.....

```
<p:commandButton value="button" id="buttonInTable"
                                    icon="ui-icon-edit" style="margin-left: -5px;"
                                    update=":mainForm:tabview:tabForm:ven " />
```

Comment: tabtab is the tab component ID .it is in the first line of code.

Comment: Before Ahmet Emre Kilinc edit it, the first line was not viewable on your posting. Voting down someone who is willing to help you based on your wrong posting is not very helpful

Comment: I edit my answer. But I am not in the mood to explain it in detail after I was downvoted

Comment: i am really sorry. I think it was by mistake. i just noticed it.